# Prove there exists such $k$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $D(0,1)$, continuous on $\overline{D}(0,1)$
> s.t $f(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1$ and $0\leq\arg z\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$
> for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^*.$
>
> a) Let
> $g(z)=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}z\right)$. Prove
> $g(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1$.
>
> b) Prove that $g=0$ on $D(0,1)$. Then show
> that $f=0$ on $D(0,1)$.

Actually, I can do part b) by using Maximum modulus principle. I'm stuck at part a). Here are my thoughts for a)
Notice that $\left\vert e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}z\right\vert=1$ when $|z|=1$. I just need to show that there exists $k\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ s.t $\arg (e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}z)\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$ since then I can make use of the hypothesis $$f(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1, 0\leq\arg z\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{n}.$$
Could someone help me how to prove there exists such $k$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that the multiplication by $e^\frac{2k\pi i}{n}$ is just a simple rotation with the angle $\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ as $e^\frac{2k\pi i}{n}=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n})$. So as $k$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$, the angle of rotations grow with the exact amount. By pigeonhole principle, there will be a good $k$, as the difference of the angles of the rotations are exactly the needed bound $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Basically we use pigeonhole principle to show that if we rotate $z$ by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, then after at most $n-1$ rotations, we get an image of $z$ in every angle around the origin of size $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. (But actually we do not need it: as it starts from one of the angles of size $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, one of the images will fall into the desired angle.)

Comment: How pigeonhole principle is used here?

Comment: Is it better now? I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you!